# Splitting field of $f(x)=x^7-3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and its degree

Tags: polynomials, roots, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

The roots of $f$ has the form $\sqrt[7]{3}\,\gamma^{n}$, where $\gamma=\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}$ and $n\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

I saw that, if $K$ is the root field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, so $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{3},\sqrt[7]{3}\,\gamma)$, because
$$\sqrt[7]{3}\gamma^{2}=\frac{\sqrt[7]{3}\gamma\cdot\sqrt[7]{3}\gamma}{\sqrt[7]{3}}\quad\textrm{and}\quad \sqrt[7]{3}\gamma^{n}=\frac{\sqrt[7]{3}\gamma^{n-1}\cdot\sqrt[7]{3}\gamma}{\sqrt[7]{3}}. $$
I'm trying to work with the extensions $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{3})\subset K$.

We have $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=\deg (x^7-3)=7$ because of Eisenstein's criterion.

But I'm having some problems with calculating $[K:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{3})].$

Obviously, $f\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{3})[x]$ satisfies $f(\sqrt[7]{3}\gamma)=0$, but I don't know if this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{3})[x]$. What can I do?

Comment: $K$ is generated over $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\sqrt[7]{3}$ and $\gamma$. The degree of the first is $7$; the degree of the second is $6$. Since they are of coprime degree, the degree of the iterated extension is the product of the degrees, so $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = 42$; the degree of $\gamma$ is $6$ because it is a root of $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = (x^7-1)/(x-1)$, which is irreducible (it is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_7(x)$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already found that
$$K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{3},\sqrt[7]{3}\gamma)=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{3},\gamma),$$
and that $[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{3}):\Bbb{Q}]=7$. Next note that $[\Bbb{Q}(\gamma):\Bbb{Q}]=6$ and that $K$ is the compositum of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{3})$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\gamma)$, so $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=7\times6=42$.